# Cannot use named anchors with Facebook tab link

Tags: facebook, tabs, anchor, share, named

I'm attempting to put a named anchor on a part of our Facebook tab and add "#anchor" to the shared URL so when users click the shared link it will take them directly to the proper content on the tab.

I added  to my tab and then recoded the FB Feed Dialog URL so

```
link=http://www.facebook.com/mybhg?sk=app_279723102083145#quiz
```

and

```
actions={name:'name',link:'http://www.facebook.com/mybhg?sk=app_279723102083145#quiz'}
```

In testing the dialog displayed an error saying both of these were invalid links:

- Requires valid redirect URI
- actions should be a JSON-encoded dictionary with "name" and "link" keys

So I bit.ly'd them which Facebook accepted and you can share the short URL. When users click the shared link though, the correct URL is used (with "#quiz") but the browser does not snap to the anchor location.

Since FB failed on the original URL, I suspect they aren't set up to parse #named anchors in their URLs, but I wanted to put it out to the community and see if someone has made it work (or confirmed it doesn't.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL fragments (the **#**) can't be read on the server side.

What you can do is use the `app_data` parameter, which is forwarded to you on the `signed_request` parameter, parse it accordingly, and have some Javascript to force the jump yourself.

Comment: This looks correct to me--too bad FB does not allow standard named anchors. I found more information on the [updated signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/) and the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) on it.